# Confused in DDA algorithm , need some help

Tags: algorithm, graphics, dda

I need help regarding DDA algorithm , i'm confused by the tutorial which i found online on DDA Algo , here is the link to that tutorial

> http://i.thiyagaraaj.com/tutorials/computer-graphics/basic-drawing-techniques/1-dda-line-algorithm

Example:

```
xa,ya=>(2,2)
xb,yb=>(8,10)
dx=6
dy=8

xincrement=6/8=0.75
yincrement=8/8=1

1)     for(k=0;k<8;k++)
xincrement=0.75+0.75=1.50
yincrement=1+1=2
1=>(2,2)

2)     for(k=1;k<8;k++)
xincrement=1.50+0.75=2.25
yincrement=2+1=3
2=>(3,3)
```

Now i want to ask that , how this line came xincrement=0.75+0.75=1.50 , when it is written in theory that

"If the slope is greater than  1 ,the roles of x any y at the unit y intervals Dy=1  and compute each successive y values.
Dy=1

```
m= Dy / Dx
m= 1/ (  x2-x1 )
m = 1 / ( xk+1 – xk  )

xk+1   =  xk   +  ( 1 / m )
```

"

it should be     `xincrement=x1 (which is 2) + 0.75 = 2.75`

or i am understanding it wrong , can any one please teach me the how  it's done  ?

Thanks a lot)

Comment: It doesn't look like a C++ question to me.

Comment: yes , its C proggy , sorry for mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a bit of confusion here.

To start with, let's assume 0 <= slope <= 1. In this case, you advance one pixel at a time in the X direction. At each X step, you have a current Y value. You then figure out whether the "ideal" Y value is closer to your current Y value, or to the next larger Y value. If it's closer to the larger Y value, you increment your current Y value. Phrased slightly differently, you figure out whether the error in using the current Y value is greater than half a pixel, and if it is you increment your Y value.

If slope > 1, then (as mentioned in your question) you swap the roles of X and Y. That is, you advance one pixel at a time in the Y direction, and at each step determine whether you should increment your current X value.

Negative slopes work pretty much the same, except you decrement instead of incrementing.

Comment: you seems to be teaching me bresenham's algorithm , even more confused if you're telling about DDA , can please tell it more discriptively?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Pixels locations are integer values.  Ideal line equations are in real numbers.  So line drawing algorithms convert the real numbers of a line equation into integer values.  The hard and slow way to draw a line would be to evaluate the line equation at each x value on your array of pixels.  Digital Differential Analyzers optimize that process in a number of ways.

First, DDAs take advantage of the fact that at least one pixel is known, the start of the line.  From that pixel, the DDAs calculate the next pixel in the line, until they reach the end point of the line.

Second, DDAs take advantage of the fact that along either the x or y axis, the next pixel in the line is always the next integer value towards the end of the line. DDA's figure out which axis by evaluating the slope.  Positive slopes between 0 and 1 will increment the x value by 1. Positive slopes greater than one will increment the y value by 1.  Negative slopes between -1 and 0 will increment the x value by -1, and negative slopes less than -1 will increment the y value by -1.

Thrid, DDAs take advantage of the fact that if the change in one direction is 1, the change in the other direction is a function of the slope.  Now it becomes much more difficult to explain in generalities.  Therefore I'll just consider positive slopes between 0 and 1.  In this case, to find the next pixel to plot, x is incremented by 1, and the change in y is calculated.  One way to calculate the change in y is just add the slope to the previous y, and round to the integer value.  This doesn't work unless you maintain the y value as a real number.  Slopes greater than one can just increment y by 1, and calculate the change in x.

Fourth, some DDAs further optimize the algorithm by avoiding floating point calculations. For example, Bresenham's line algorithm is a DDA optimized to use integer arithmetic.

In this example, a line from (2, 2) to (8, 10), the slope is 8/6, which is greater than 1.  The first pixel is at (2, 2).  The next pixel is calculated by incrementing the y value by 1, and adding the change in x (the inverse slope, of dx/dy = 6/8 = .75) to x. The value of x would be 2.75 which is rounded to 3, and (3, 3) is plotted.  The third pixel would increment y again, and then add the change in x to x (2.75 + .75 = 3.5).  Rounding would plot the third pixel at (4, 4).  The fourth pixel would then plot (5, 4), since y would be incremented by 1, but x would be incremented by .75, and equal 4.25.

From this example, can you see the problem with your code?